# Why does numpy.corrcoef() returns nan?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

Trying to build a regression model, but got a problem I can't solve.
Have googled and read everything about it but nothing works. Have this dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 334195 entries, 0 to 334194
Data columns (total 12 columns):
type         334195 non-null int64
zipcode      334195 non-null int64
sqft         334195 non-null float64
lotsize      334195 non-null float64
beds         334195 non-null float64
baths        334195 non-null float64
year         334195 non-null float64
s_num        334195 non-null int64
s_rate       334195 non-null float64
s_dist       334195 non-null float64
crimes       334195 non-null float64
target       334195 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(9), int64(3)
```

Trying to do this:

```html
data = pd.read_csv('data_prep_sale')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df.drop(['target'],axis=1)
y = pd.Series(df['target'])

trimmed_feature_names = []
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    correlation = np.corrcoef(x.iloc[:,i],y)[0,1]
    if abs(correlation) > 0.5:
        feature_name = x.columns[i]
        print(feature_name, correlation)
        trimmed_feature_names.append(feature_name)
```

and keep getting this matrix for all the x:

```html
array([[ 1., nan],
       [nan, nan]])
```

This is a data sample:

```html
type zipcode sqft lotsize beds baths year s_num s_rate s_dist crimes target
4 28387 2900.0 0.0 4.0 3.5 2019.0 8 5.20 5.54 6.0 144.137931
4 99216 1947.0 5828.0 3.0 3.0 2019.0 3 4.00 1.33 3.1 159.219312
3 90049 3000.0 8626.0 3.0 2.0 1967.0 3 6.67 1.96 4.4 965.000000
1 75205 6457.0 8220.0 5.0 8.0 2006.0 4 9.25 0.75 4.6 370.915286
```

[Link to the complete data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KyhlFoBQi3RfsVFPf8xaO5j3geus2JpK/view?usp=drivesdk)

Please, help me! Need any ideas!

Comment: To be able to reproduce this issue, we need you to share `data_prep_sale.csv` file with us?

Comment: Have added the link to the question (not sure how to share the file correctly here).

Comment: You can't upload file to SO, that's what I meant

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. What is SO?

Comment: SO: stands for Stack Overflow... and it's totally OK. We're here to help :)

Comment: Thank you! So what should I do? Is the link to google drive enough or should I do anything else? Need help very much!

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the uploaded file, there are some `inf` values in the `target` column... like the ones at row: 43, 283, 372, ...etc. So, to fix this issue you have to remove all `inf` rows. Also, there is a better way to find the correlation between `target` and other features. Both are shown in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data_prep_sale.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# remove any (inf, -inf, nan) values
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()

# find the correlation between target other features
print(df.corr()["target"])
```

As you can see from the output of the correlation, all values are way lower than `0.5`.

Comment: also, i would check if features .dtypes are float32 or higher, not float16 just in case.